# Why do we need the SD line?

Tags: standard-deviation

Why we need the SD line(magenta) and how does it help us, 
besides just passing through all `standard units of x` and `standard units of y` pair points on the `xy` plot?

The SD line goes through the point of averages, and has slope equal to `SDY/SDX` if the correlation coefficient r is greater than or equal to zero. The SD line has slope `−SDY/SDX` if r is negative.

http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/SticiGui/Text/regression.htm

[image]

Comment: Please explain the context of your question and tell us what the "SD line" is.  Although many people could make reasonable guesses, this is not a sufficiently standard term to be readily understood.  And what, exactly, would a "standard deviation point" be?

Comment: @whuber I edited it, is it clear now ?
thanks

Comment: Although the answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2700 does not say so, the gray line shown in its third (last) figure is the same as your "SD line."

Comment: @whuber I don't understand why you write "your SD line" in quotes, it's not mine nor did I invent it, the word "SD Line" is mentioned in "Statistics 4th Edition by Freedman,Pisani and Purves"

Comment: This question is not clear !! please provide some information on what an SD Line is

Comment: @raK1 I updated the question , also added where I found this SD Line (Berkeley course of statistics)

Comment: @Oleg - The magenta line is not the standard deviation line. It is the linear regression line. The grey lines are the standard deviation lines. In which case they represent the mean + STD and the mean - STD.